# Java: Get integer value from URL

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am trying to get a String out of URL.

I am using Regular Expression.

```
String url = "http://localhost/htc/android/htc-incredible/259164-gpid";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.+/(\\d+)-gpid$"); 
Matcher tagmatch = regex.matcher( url );
System.out.println(tagmatch.group(0));
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

What I am doing wrong:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `group(1)` (the contents of the first capturing group), not `group(0)` (the entire match).

Oh, and of course you need to actually do a search:

```
tagmatch.find();
System.out.println(tagmatch.group(1));
```

Comment: Updated the question with Exception.

Comment: Hell yeah! Thats what I was missing. Thanks @Tim. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `lastIndexOf` in combination with `split` to get the part of the url you want. Code will look like this

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).split("-")[0] //prints 259164
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
String url = "http://localhost/htc/android/htc-incredible/259164-gpid";
url.substring(url.indexOf('/',url.indexOf("htc-incredible/"))+1,url.indexOf("-gpid"));
```